# Sending multiple rows x cols to Flash from PHP

Tags: php, database, flash, actionscript-3

I have a Mysql database and I am trying to import multiple records with multiple columns into Flash AS3 using PHP. My problem is I am able to make it work with a single column and multiple records but for multiple columns I am not being able to format it correctly. What i wish to have is an array(of records) of associative arrays(of columns) i.e. I want to be able to partition the output (from php) based on '|' and store it in a flash array and then be able to access name,id for each of them (see below the code).

the php part ->

```
<?php
......//connection to mysql db ...etc.
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$output = "success=$db&myArrayForFlash=";

//error check
...
//form the return string
while($myRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $arrayElement = "&name=".$myRow['name'];        
        $arrayElement = $arrayElement."&id=".$myRow['id'];
        $output = $output."$arrayElement" . "|";
    }
}

echo($output);
?>
```

the flash part->

```
function completeHandler(e:Event):void
        {
            if(e.target.data.success=="1"){
                var myArray:String = e.target.data.myArrayForFlash;  //empty
                var myCol:String = myArray[0]['id'];
                this.var= e.target.data.myArrayForFlash.split("|");

                //do something else
            }
            else
            {
                Alert.show("Query failed. \n");
            }
        }
```

the problem is I get an array of names,id but the myArrayForFlash is empty (which is kind of expected).Is there any way to get past this?

I am a total newbie to flash/php so any help is useful!

Here's a [reference](http://friendsofed.infopop.net/4/OpenTopic?a=tpc&s=989094322&f=1973013165&m=5393017976) and [another](http://www.ultrashock.com/forum/viewthread/90294/) that I used. (I tried searching for something similar but all I get is returning multiple rows with 1 column or 1 row with multiple columns)

Comment: what does `trace(e.target.data);` show?

Comment: so it has something like name array - name[0],name[1].... and id array id[0],id[1]... and they display correct values.

Comment: `name` and `id` arrays have the same length and for every `i` `id[i]` is correct for `name[i]` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function createList(names: Array, ids: Array):Object{
    if(names.length != ids.length){
        trace('incorrect input');
        return null;/*you may throw an error as well*/
    }
    var hash:Object = new Object();
    for(var i: int = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        hash[ids[i]] = names[i];/*or hash[names[i]] = ids[i] if name is a key*/
    }
    return hash;
}
```

**upd:**

```
function createList(names: Array, ids: Array):Array{
    if(names.length != ids.length){
        trace('incorrect input');
        return null;/*you may throw an error as well*/
    }
    var hash:Array = new Array();
    for(var i: int = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        hash.push({id:ids[i], name:names[i]});
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: well it's kind of necessary to put it in the form of an array of associative arrays. is that possible?

Comment: @sg88 - not sure i understand the structure. you mean an array (with numeric index) that has key-value pairs as elements?

Comment: yup that's exactly what I wan. so that I can access elements as myArray[i]['name'] for example